# How Much of A Planet-Sized Spaceship is Useable?

Tags: technology, planets, spaceships, engineering, caves

Okay, let's say we have a spaceship the size of a planet. Let's put the radius at 3 Earth radii, and the mass at 7.5 Earth masses. Its hull is made of a space metal with a density of 3500 kg/m^3, and a compressive strength of 8.5 TPa. What is the maximum amount of interior that can be hollowed out without it collapsing in on itself to accommodate crew? And at what depth can interior chambers no longer be supported?

Comment: @ErikHall: OK, deleted my comment and waiting to see if somebody has an insight on what the OP meant.

Comment: @AlexP oh god now i have to give it a Shoot D: What did you made me do ?

Comment: What I'm asking is how much empty space filled with air my megastructure can have without collapsing in on itself.

Comment: This question is missing details. Referencing [A Structurally Self-Supporting Hollow Earth](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/110758/40609), we realize that the contents of the shell contribute significantly to whether or not the shell can exist. For example, in the vacuum of intergalactic space, an entirely empty shell would enjoy 99.99999% emptiness. But as soon as you start adding stuff, like an atmosphere and water/fluids, the characteristics of the infrastructure material almost become irrelevant. Filled only with air, that much internal mass (\*continued\*)...

Comment: that much internal mass will cause the center/core to turn to a superheated plasma, causing all kinds of problems. And that's just air. I'm afraid without a very detailed explanation of what you intend to have inside the sphere, the question is scientifically moot. I'd just design it to your story's needs and move on. After all, you've already created a material out of Clarkean Magic. It's an easy step to not worry about this detail. (And asking us to engineer a mega structure is a bit out of the Stack's scope....)

Comment: I'm just going to say right now that all you are doing is throwing out random numbers and expecting us to do the work for you. Clearly, you did not do research, or, you are refusing to believe such research.

Answer (score 1):

Your 'ship' is large enough to generate significant gravity. Hence, without clarketech(ie anti-gravity), such a ship is impossible. There is no known material that can resist such pressures, and even if such a material exists, it would likely heat up to the point it might melt. Already a couple kilometers down, you would experience pressures similar or more extreme to those of the Challenger Deep. Let alone hundreds of kilometers down. 3500kg/meter cubed? Seriously, that is less than HALF the density of iron. Do your research before asking a question.

Edit: A *tunnel* through the ship? Did you do your research at *all*?

Answer (score -2):

Okay, here it goes. The surface gravity is .833 g, or 8.18 N/kg. Rocks have a compressive strength of up to 130 MPa, and we're dealing with a compressive strength that's over 65 thousand times higher. Caves can only get as deep as 3 km on Earth, but with this spaceship, we can get depths of 235 thousand km, so a tunnel leading from one side of the ship to the other is 100% possible. The pressure of the center of the Earth is 360 GPa, and triple that, and you have a pressure of 1.08 TPa. A honeycomb structure can definitely hold together the thing, but there's the habitability of the lower layers. They would get hotter and more pressurized, but that would create convection currents that help the upper layer's biosphere.

And if there's enough heat and pressure at the core, that could be used for nuclear reactions.

Comment: (a) This doesn't answer your own question. (b) [Weird things happen at the TPa level](https://advances.sciencemag.org/content/2/7/e1600341), including induced superconductivity, which means your metal would likely corrode somewhere in the middle from a form of galvanic corrosion. What's going on here, Tyson? It's like you're cranking through equations but haven't thought through the consequences or conditions of your question. It's not the first time I've seen you do it. Are you actually building a world, or are you just chasing questions that tickle your fancy?

Comment: I'm coming up with ideas for future and current stories.

Comment: a honeycomb structure CANNOT hold up the ship

Comment: you realize that a material that can resist such forces does not exist?

Comment: without antigravity this is impossible